# Slim Callable UserController does not exist RuntimeException

Tags: php, model-view-controller, slim

Hi i am new to slim i stuck on this anyone help please

**routes.php**

```
$app->get('/', 'UserController:index');
```

**dependencis.php**

```
$container['src\UserController'] = function ($container) {
    return new \src\UserController($container->get('settings'));
};
```

UserController.php

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use App\src\Controller;
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function index(Request $request, Response $response) {
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

and **controller.php**

```
namespace App\src;

class Controller {
    protected $container;
    public function __construct($c) {
        $this->container = $c;
    }

    public function __get($property) {
        if($this->container->has($property)) {
            return $this->container->get($property);
        }
        return $this->{$property};
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you should return `new \src\UserController()` in your container, not `new \App\src\UserController`?

Comment: $container['src\UserController'] = function ($container) {
       return new \src\UserController();
   };
here it is itry most of this by changing path \src\UserController(); and
return new \src\UserController($contianer);

Comment: Hi @ShahzadNasir, I got a problem that looks like yours. May I get help from you for this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449493/slim-framework-routing-http-requests-to-static-class-methods . Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you have defined your route as:

```
$app->get('/', 'UserController:index');
```

Then you need to define your DI factory as:

```
$container['UserController'] = function ($container) {
    // return an instantiated UserController here.
};
```

You should also look up how namespaces and PSR-4's mapping of namespace name to directory work. In general there is never a `src` in a namespace name, but you do see a namespace such as `App` mapped to a directory call `src` in the Composer autoloader as specified in composer.json.

Usually, it looks something like this:

```js
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

This means that you have a directory called `src` and any class inside that directory, will have a base namespace of `App` and then any other directories act as sub-namespaces.

i.e. if you have a file called `src/Controllers/UserController.php`, then the class definition in that file will be:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
class UserController
{
    // methods here
}
```

Note also that the capitalisation of the filename matches the class name and that the capitalisation of the directories match the capitalisation of the sub-namespaces.

To continue the example, I would expect the DI factory to look like this:

```
$container['UserController'] = function ($container) {
    return new \App\Controllers\UserController($container->get('settings'));
};
```

It's really unusual to see `src` in a namespace definition, so go through and check that your namespaces and files on disk all match up as the code in the question is inconsistent.

Comment: @Rob worked for me too, and gave me a better understanding of how namespacing and auto loader works better than other manuals I read online.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the name of the file **(controller.php)** that holds controller class. they must be the same.

**for example :**

if you have **Contoller.php** file you must make the name of class like this **C**ontroller.

in your example you have **Controller.php** file with capital letter of **C**
but, the class **c**ontroller doesn't start with a capital letter.

so, make sure the **file name** is same as the **class name**.

hope this will help you .

Comment: Hi Mohammed, thanks for your response.  Would you please clarify your sentence, "they must me same."  Do you mean, "they must be the same"?  I was going to correct this type-o; however, I realized that the statement is still very ambiguous.  Please clarify, what must be the same?  For example, do you mean the file names, directories, paths, classes, etc. or what?

Also please don't mark your answer "resolved". The original poster will indicate if your answer has solved the question.

Comment: Hi David John, I really do appreciate your advices.

Answer (score 0):

in my case this is work, i hope for you too

**home_controller.php**

```php
namespace Apa\Kabar;

use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

class HomeController
{
   protected $container;

   // constructor receives container instance
   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
       $this->container = $container;
   }

   public function home($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response->write('apa kabar');
   }

   public function contact($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
   }
}
```

**route.php***

```php
require __DIR__. '/../controller/home_controller.php';

$configuration = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
    ],
];
$con = new Container($configuration);

$app = new App($con);
$con = $app->getContainer();

$con['HomeController'] = function($con) {
    return new HomeController($con);
};

$app->get('/home', 'HomeController:home');
```