# Routing HTTP requests to static class methods

Tags: php, rest, api, slim

I just started using Slim Framework to create my rest API. Everything works well until I try to route HTTP request to a static class method (I used the anonymous function before). Below is my new route code on `index.php`:

```
include "vendor/autoload.php";
$config = ['settings' => [
               'addContentLengthHeader' => false,
               'displayErrorDetails'    => true,
               'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true
            ]
          ];

$app = new \Slim\App($config);
$app->get('/user/test', '\App\Controllers\UserController:test');
$app->run();
```

And below is my `UserController` class on `UserController.php`

```
class UserController{
    public function test($request, $response, $args){
        $array = ['message'=>'your route works well'];
        return $response->withStatus(STAT_SUCCESS)
                        ->withJson($array);
    }
}
```

Error details:

```
Type   : RuntimeException
Message: Callable \Controllers\UserController does not exist
File   : /var/www/html/project_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php
```

Below is my project folder tree

```
project_api/
           index.php
           vendor/
                 slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php

           Controllers/
                      UserController.php
```

my `composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.8",
        "sergeytsalkov/meekrodb": "*",
        "slim/http-cache": "^0.3.0"
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Controllers\\": "Controllers/"
    }
}
```

Comment: you called the class `User` not `UserController`

Comment: Hi @jmattheis, thanks for the correction. Changed the class name and still got the same error

Comment: Do you have composer autoload defined?

Comment: @jmattheis I don't have. added my `composer.json`. any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181181/composer-autoloading

Comment: @jmattheis, added autoload to the composer and run `composer update`. use reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500702/slim-3-autoloader. Still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your namespace is define improperly. In your `composer.json`, class `UserController` under the namespace `Controllers`.

you should define a namespace at the top of your `UserController.php`:

```
namespace Controllers;
```

and change `$app->get()` in your `index.php` to:

```
$app->get('/user/test', 'Controllers\UserController:test');
```